# res.send() not able to send entire base64 string to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, base64, local-storage

Basically, I'm trying to capture screenshots of websites and at the same time trying to store them into local storage of the browser. So I am taking help of webshot(which is an npm package and a light wrapper around phantomjs).But unfortunately, res.send() is not able to send the entire data to the client. That's why my image appears as only 25% of the original image, as it sends only some amount of the base64 encoded string. **specificData which is the base64 encoded string of the actual buffer data fetched by webshot is not sent at whole over to the client**. *Below is my server side code*

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();


let webshot = require('webshot');
let specificData;

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("let's get started");
});

app.get('/imageViewer',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

app.get('/storeImageToLocalStorage',(req,res,next)=>{
    let renderStream = webshot('stackoverflow.com');
    renderStream.on('data', function(data) {
        specificData=data.toString('base64');
        next();
    });
},(req,res)=>{
    res.send(specificData);
});

app.listen(5676,()=>{
console.log("listening at http://localhost:5676");});
```

**Below is my index File which is sent when get request is received from the client**. Then the specificData is fetched from the server which is actually *a chunk received from the server end due to the shortcoming of res.send()*. I have searched all over the net of how to fix this but I couldn't find any relevant solution. That is why I have turned to stackoverflow to get my question answered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="tableBanner" style="height: 40vh;width: 40vw">
<script>
    $(()=>{
        let bannerImg = document.getElementById('tableBanner');
        $.get('/storeImageToLocalStorage',(specificData)=>{
            localStorage.setItem('specificData',specificData);
            bannerImg.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+localStorage.getItem('specificData');
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are overwriting everytime data is received and passing to next middleware on first chunk of data receive:

```
renderStream.on('data', function(data) {
        specificData += data.toString('base64');  //append
});

//calling next() when data has stopped listening
renderStream.on('end', function() {
       next();
})
```